# will metro style app support local database

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm developing metro app for windows 8 tablet using XAML and C#, so is there any effective way to store the data in local database(like SQLLite which is used in iPhone), so my questions are

1. will metro app support local database access ?
2. If support which is the effective way to achieve it and which database is used to store data?

Can any one send me any articles or links about this, please help me Thanks in advance

Comment: "windows ipad"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SQLite in a Metro-style app on Windows 8. You can find appropriate binaries on [their download page](http://sqlite.org/download.html).

Comment: Also see a great blog on this by Tim Heuer http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/06/05/howto-video-using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx

Comment: And as announced by Microsoft during the Windows Phone Developer Summit (June 24th) SQLite will be supported by Windows Phone 8, soIthink SQLite is de facto solution for WinRT local database for now.

Comment: That's interessting. What about SQL Server Compact and W8 Metro Style App?